# Should I document overriden hashCode() and toString()?

Tags: java

Is it desirable to document the overriden `hashCode()` and `toString()` or similar methods in Java? (not including `equals()` and similar of course) 
What are the conventions?

Comment: You could state how the object is represented by a string. Imo, documentation for `hashCode()` is unnecessary.

Comment: its certainly not undesirable ! ( particularly the `hashCode()`

Comment: I'd say unless you have something extra to add to the original documentation, extra documentation shouldn't be necessary

Comment: The moment your `equals` method becomes complex enough to justify Javadoc is the moment your `equals` method is doing **too much.**  Same goes for `hashCode`.

Comment: @Makoto not necessarily... for example, the ``equals`` method of [``Set``](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is defined in a mathematically rigorous manner...

Comment: I agree with @user3580294 and would add: If your `hashCode` does something not covered by the original documentation, then your hashCode is rather weird. Users of a class shouldn't really have to care on how `hashCode` is implemented. This is different for `equals`, as @k_g's example shows.

Comment: If your `hashCode()` might have interesting/undesirable distribution attributes (and you cannot improve it) then I would consider documenting that characteristic. `toString()` and `equals()` don't require documentation - if they don't do what they're supposed to do, then fix 'em(!)

Comment: @k_g:  I would expect that set equivalence could use *some* elaboration, but that's because it's based in math.  For most of the things that normal people do, I would be shocked if there was a complex implementation of `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle's JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) Guide:

> So if the documentation of the overridden or implemented method is sufficient, you do not need to add documentation for `m()`.

If your hashCode or toString are doing something different to the documentation in Object then you need to amend the code rather than the documentation. As anyone using these methods without access to the JavaDoc will expect them to behave as documented in Object.

JavaDoc:

[hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)
[toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: I would just add that if your hashCode or toString are doing something different you *shouldn't be Overriding them*, and should use different methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some special algorithm that needs documenting, I would write inline comments // ..., but this should be of no concern to the API user, who is relying on the contract expressed by the inherited Javadoc, so I wouldn't write it as Javadoc comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to document them.  For instance, if an object is intended to be a value returned by a Swing model (ListModel, TableModel, etc.), its `toString` method may return a display string intended to be displayed to the user, rather than a string meant for debugging.  I often like to make it clear whether an object's toString is suitable for display to an end user.

I will document `equals` to indicate which properties or what state constitutes equality, like [URI.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [List.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) do.  Similarly, it is useful to point out the properties or state on which `hashCode` relies, especially for mutable objects, since it allows a developer to avoid changing that state when the object is used as a hash key.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a reason to have a specified algorithm for computing the hash-code, you should document that algorithm for the `hashCode()` method. Java itself does this for [`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29):

> a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as
>
> ```
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```
>
> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

For most other cases, however, the general contract of `Object.hashCode()` requiring it to be consistent with `equals()` is enough documentation.

Bloch in *Effective Java* recommends documenting the format of the `toString()` message **for *value classes***. He also notes that in that case you should provide a also provide a parsing function (a static factory method) that creates an object of the class given its `String` representation..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't override the `Object` class's documentation of these methods, since it describes the contract that all implementations (including yours) can be expected to follow.  It *may* be appropriate to extend the inherited documentation with *additional* notes about your implementation.  You can do that like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * <p>
 * In this implementation...
 */
```

The Javadoc tool will insert the superclass documentation in place of the `{@inheritDoc}` tag, so that the output will consist of that superclass documentation followed by your additional notes.